# Finding the x-value corresponding to a y-value found using Nearest

Tags: index, nearest

I have a large 2d array of infinite precision named "data" of x values and y values. I am using `Nearest` to find the y-value closest to a specified number, say 0.00064.

```
closestY = Nearest[data[[All,2]],0.00064]
```

> ```
> closestY = 0.000639`
> ```

Now, I intend to find the position of this value in the list so I can find the corresponding x-value like so:

```
Position [closestY]
```

And it returns empty. However, if I physically copy and paste the result of closestY into my position call like so:

```
Position[0.000639`]
```

It returns the correct position index in the list.

In guessing Mathematica isn't putting full precision into my call of  closestY, and I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `nf = Nearest[data[[All, 2]] -> data[[All, 1]]]; nf[0.00064]`

Answer (score 1):

`Nearest` returns a list of the values it finds even if it only finds one. Therefore, you extract the value from that list.

```
 SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[1., {5, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{0.425905, 0.391023}, {0.347069, 0.453741}, {0.555963, 0.289169}, 
>  {0.296848, 0.206408}, {0.32517, 0.973325}}
> ```

```
 y = Nearest[data[[All, 2]], 0.25][[1]]
```

> `0.289169`

```
 Position[y][data]
```

> `{{3, 2}}`

Answer (score 1):

You say you want the $x$-value corresponding to the nearest $y$-value. For example, given @mgoldberg's dataset:

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[1., {5, 2}]
```

> {{0.425905, 0.391023}, {0.347069, 0.453741}, {0.555963, 0.289169}, {0.296848, 
>     0.206408}, {0.32517, 0.973325}}

You could use:

```
nf = Nearest[data[[All, 2]] -> data[[All, 1]]];
nf[.25]
```

> {0.555963}

You could also use:

```
Nearest[data[[All, 2]] -> data[[All, 1]], .25]
```

> {0.555963}

The version where you create a [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction) and then use the [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction) (my first method) is typically more useful.